# Why when the sum of components of $v$ and of $w$ is $0$, then every combination of $v$ and $w$ has components that sum is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Every combination of $v=(1,-2,1)$ and $w=(0,1,-1)$ has components that add to *0*

Reason provided by solution: The components of every $cv + dw$ add to zero because the components of $v$ and of $w$ add to zero.

I don't know why. My method to get 0 is very normal and standard. I just list all components of $cv + dw$, that is $(c, -2c+d, c-d)$. I then find $c-2c+d+c-d=0$.

Why the reason provided by solution is correct? I don't understand why when the sum of components of $v$ is $0$, the sum of components of $w$ is $0$, then Every combination of $v$ and $w$ has components that sum is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have precisely show why by this steps

$$u=cv + dw=(c, -2c+d, c-d)\implies  c-2c+d+c-d=0$$

which proves the statement.

To be more general we can consider

- $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots)$ with $\sum v_i=0$
- $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3,\ldots)$ with $\sum w_i=0$

then by the same argument

$$u=cv+dw=(cv_1+dw_1,cv_2+dw_2,\ldots) \implies c\sum v_i+d\sum w_i=0$$

The underlying property for which it is true is linearity.

---

Another equivalent way is use dot product with $u=(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ indeed

$$v\cdot u=0 \,\land\, w\cdot u =0 \implies (cv+dw)\cdot u=cv\cdot u + d w\cdot u=0$$

Comment: This is my method. But it's different from author's solution. The author here wants to emphasize that: when the sum of components of v is 0, the sum of components of w is 0, then Every combination of v and w has components that sum is zero. And I don't know why this is true. Notice that in author's solution, v and w are general vectors.

Comment: @YaoZhao This is a trivial property by linearity. Your method is fine and we can use the same argument to prove it in general.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think about it is that the "sum of components" function

$$f(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i$$

is a linear function $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. Therefore, for any vectors $v$ and $w$, if $f(v) = f(w) = 0$, then

$$f(cv + dw) = c\cdot f(v) + d\cdot f(w) = c\cdot 0 + d\cdot 0 = 0$$